# How to detect anomalies in multivariate, multiple time-series data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, outliers, anomaly-detection

I am trying to find anomalies in a huge sales-transactions dataset (more than 1 million observations), with thousands of unique customers. Same customer can purchase multiple times on the same date. Dataset contains a mix of both random and seasonal transactions. A dummy sample of my data is below:

```
Date      CustomerID     TransactionType      CompanyAccountNum      Amount
01.01.19  1              Sales                111xxx                 100
01.01.19  1              Credit               111xxx                 -3100
01.01.19  4              Sales                111xxx                 100
02.01.19  3              Sales                311xxx                 100
02.01.19  1              Refund               211xxx                 -2100
03.01.19  4              Sales                211xxx                 3100
```

Which algorithm/approach would suit this problem best? I have tried a multivariate FBprophet model (on python) so far and received less-than-satisfactory results.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the `pyod` package, methods like isolation forest or HBOS.

It's advertised as 'a comprehensive and scalable Python toolkit for detecting outlying objects in multivariate data' but your mileage may vary in terms of performance, so first check out their [benchmarks](https://pyod.readthedocs.io/en/latest/benchmark.html#execution-time).

Answer (score 0):

If you have time series data, it is better to apply some methods like moving average or exponential smoothing your data to remove trends and seasonalities. Otherwise, all data points involved in seasonality or trend periods will be labeled as anomalies.